# Dynamically create radio buttons from array in EXTJS5

Tags: extjs5

I would like to create radio buttons from data in an array that is passed into a custom component.  I think I need to use config properties for this, but I am hitting a wall.

Here is the custom component:

```
Ext.define('carrier.view.components.jbRadioButtons',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.button.Button'
    ],
    config: {
        alias: 'widget.tstBtn',
        title: 'customButtons',
        width: 300,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        my_Array : [
            {
                xtype: 'radio',
                id: 'rb2',
                name: 'rbGroup',
                checked: false,
                hideLabel: true
            } 
        ],

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                columns: 1,
                vertical: true,
                items: my_Array

                /*[{
                    xtype: 'radio',
                    id: 'rb2',
                    name: 'rbGroup',
                    checked: false,
                    hideLabel: true} 
               ]*/
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Here is what I am passing in:

```
xtype:'tstBtn',
my_Array : [
    {
        xtype: 'radio',
        id: 'rb2',
        name: 'rbGroup',
        checked: false,
        hideLabel: true
    } 
]
```

I keep getting "my_Array" is not defined.

Comment: This is not an ExtJS related issue. The error is basic javascript... You should study javascript [variables and object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) in more depth.

Comment: Agreed with rixo, and more specifically, in your radiogroup config, `my_Array` doesn't exist, at least, not in the scope... you might then think `this.my_Array` would work, but that's not the case, as your scope is not the class's scope in the class configs.